# javascript save the response to a file

Tags: javascript

```
data
:
"����   Phttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <?xpacket end="w"?>��,Photoshop 3.08BIM�%����ُ���  ���B~���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������M���Adobed�������Z�g�����������������↵��    ������������������  ����↵�������������      ����������  �!�1↵�"A�#2Q�a$Bbq�39Xr����CRSv�����x��������'EVw����������������
������������!1��A�"Qa  #2Bq�R����$3brs���CSc��������%467DTU�����tu������EVe�&'58dv��������?��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��П�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S�����8櫾�vՃ&əW/���V��/ɔ]��M$�(}�����0H�g=��'���Y�����w'��e�Oԟ��J↵���d�Ƭ���Wl��'R2f�9���)'4↵���>Ǘa����L���pt��R�3ټ��?�eU��A�u��i2�[y�,�����o�V=v�D����"��t��b����z�m�S�/إ|�2:-A7�%\��<�l|:�n���V���qn��H��M[�<R�V�bk�2��ˑ?ʑQ�m[�����b�������/�����4MO�!b��*��QK���a����]�������܉�Rg�.Є�y���s�7����*�O?|  ��r���(���i�:(  {1������|t���Q�?.}�G��y���W���m.ly7�����vH��)���#��*����JHi����#�����4����{���/�~&�=�4���n��ޅk���������(ۏ�5^)_���f�tӐ���_�@������pȐ���U�}>a�_��?q��߾��Ż0Y4��Q�������+��*�o�M�<�!tD�����q    �&�kV���v�Qm�������|A�S��V��.s�@�0�w���-�܀��?p��S���u/�h��F;���F>.���<�(7nٸ`�}l���]�l������ފ���`�R�N>b1�=Ʋ1O[H0r�����EVn�?̦��"X���S+$��`A��=j��$��������+�g�}���)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��џ�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb�i���o�xrų�Lr�ZjE���G@O��˜�*y�\C� ���K����f↵�Q���wu��������Zu�ڃ�踍O��nX�����F��h�2�R��&��/V||B(g z��Tz�3��4�TҰ<J���uʤW-�߶��������1�|��[�64�b���R���C����v2#lxOܗ�n7e���G�����Ǩ-����(�O���o��=.6���S�u�P3�z��L�B���o���ꏾE�(�����۵�T�x�L��ȵO�↵F�|�+s���"�  ۼf'0��@@$��������I���.T}������O./֍����j�j�z�Rْ��r�r�=� ��G�b3�����[[l��gs�kl�=�2�D^�l]�r��s�a9�p��?D���#�R����s/����� �,�ma^�����Њ���c��ǭjg7��+�Ž��s��.p{���Ꜷbɘ�4fը�ȃf��?�A"��*��ީs]\ܜ�I$���[�I�לW��b��uRL褢��G�1��s��\�/�ʉ eLB����@3���v,r:4��Q�X�p����L��{���LR�;�m����VΈ?r8A%����S�r ������v淑�o��S����I�l-e"�_Y�]����������[i.Z�����+3�����z����}���ꑘ�;k{��q,i ?�ՅTl��cOs%����������8?0���+z�׳�3B�F��(����b*�{��8�����#�q�05cb���z��Ya��B9�7����k�q��
��n��X�ٞxz�7Y�J�.�ӽ٤��?�3����+����>�����?�ή�V6���k��'↵���bi)���zJ����L�5��S0?�����(�������<&�����GQ���H��|�?�"����B!YoC㞋z��Z������c�,��*�J�zt������'�ng{�����u�����>�� ��b��2�U������F��3y��� G��u��<޻3
�4�h    ��������^<����]�\P�e�H̼�NQ���8W������2���)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��ҟ�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��b��>�\��!%�7��%o�M�;-��ŝ�`��q�I�\��5�j�W)��Vq�E���D[��(�m������K�6���V=n��E�_/�<��<�…Wk�F*�:�`�q-��Y}ǲ��h�`?��<ֶ�Y����^W��*F,���&���S]�i�%QT|���~������S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�W�������b��?MoI~Kz���yFj���4����J����uZ��IVu|2����{I����X�1���s��ɷW�q;�[g���;��[��1Z#�{<̓�G� ���`  \���a���F�I��c��zz�����W$�@�����p[��ӌ������F*�2�+���Kl��i+r�^۰l�N�i����T�!�b�������*a�=뾷����Z�Sy���ƹX�L�ˉ2yW�rY�Wfn�/4��������P*�n�͏�d�����2sxYhUn��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1J�՟�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��t݇�����f��&��L�S��MYl����.&9���e�7fQU�9RE��u�.r$����Q�_��ivrj���
�(Yݎ�Tz���I I�[Kinm��l�nͱ�ԷN�:�mm���Y�����Y݈H�ZI�QY�W�f��Ǯ��y��8�i���ɘ���l�EJi��s������Y���_� ��R�R�EB����� ����Sqq�Xm�D�ٖ�Wa��ui�����v^�O���=���↵���2���X[m��X��4�H\�nJ�X,%�>�o�`���T��Z��O;   d�Ů(��j��I�k���j��3��j"��y����ak�O��e&� @�BD�n�H�t�n�i�@m����M-4�!↵��Y�����$��]�ǰ�U�@�M�t���Eo������s�Ȃ(!���,���Z�@Y��'|��#��g�gy��2�Xv��|وx��D�~���9�;���n�a�i8���6ʲ����z���#d��tWAb�%R9�b�D@{!�ky����'��+)*��r�H����#���_�G���J��`A���=� � ������U�e�r�'w��鑫Z����W�����u��:�SӖ��L}u(��}<,����S�h��R��/�c�z���Ѹ���X↵���ʞ�ύG֏�����YI$`�����Ud�t��Պt<�$�$��N=���↵�[Cz�B�j�����t�^���G"��D��=�ڡW��w� �j��������Y�'�EU� a��f���V1�zD�\�Ҍ���to��z�PpA�@=�`��MOC�k]J&�Eb2A�#�@ �+� ���<�U&��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1J������f�������� �MV�P����lҎ�    ���]�n�VU��`�$` ~��J�!缼���d���8,�^g�FTD��f!T~&��v����-���I  �@H��㧩�FY��z�vzi��wVFU���B�����b����ߤ�2%r������'�P���}/^��O�M��R&P�6$7�w����h�7↵�ʵ�۽�M�=��H$�X�!̘����� ��C�r�Dc����������↵��nd���)�=�X���k0��u^1�5n�V�a�]��d�$�2��-�X��
����)����d1����.d���I�%b������ff$�}I$�~���XV���8�aU@��������]��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S���֟�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��`����;�����w�*v[u+��K������<-E���Q�uv��1     eي�f�8v���cH��̗�b��|F�����:n�k$��ĉ湐���:��>�̀�5l�ɔ��3���<~�?�~�o^0�Z~�ƻ��m7B�fOj(m��阂f��y����0��Ɩ�'3��fК�S�X��������U�M�B���I��)�X쒇�y?e�2�;��Lu�0��JB�'h����t����%��1������ǫ�wfbI�@@�)�W~�{^q��:�ږ�oy��"��1���=�{hC���¢�N�31��V�yLR��1Jb�f�����G<j_��������l�cX�L���ڴn��dU�lH�od�I�n������p���7X�%��g��wl;�k�7�@���������D�F$s`8�e������4m���U�$����g8��\�(�F��j����6��㛙˷��/˭:���m\�A�/"��I�m$*-+�8ͽ�L����A�&c�V_�ml��[Op�v;�
'X �䖵s��uh� r��y��~�����5��c<�����ތ�����������L�'��v�Y�����FS�KD<�r���#��m1^�j�b1`0�t�$���a�R�����/,��kI��t`����) ���
��o��W�<n��#�6�+������K������^�b��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR�Z����t<sG��3��c
    ��ܬ���T�c�����9W����I�J("?�����1��2�(   fb�T���8cԑ^�;���<�8�G��;�z��2z���u��p_��ss��1V}���z\�{��v�Z/7���}��ԵB���p�LP{dY��S{�b� Ǎ��Ge�x��n����:����~/?P����|�.��j�|�յ'[�{6�y���GC�S���>^��Y�C5��zep������|Ռ�\^4��m�t:6��o�:T&��Z��z��?-�J:$� $jQ�F�on&o� \��
��P�Kx������?�r��lT��6����Xt�Q\.��9�Ǩ(=�P�OR2I7���\t�)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��ן�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��x�D@�����}��v+��ּ⹦)LR��1Jb��)�U����ۇ�毖���F�z�h�����Iz�Ϋ��U4���Z걶����D�M�Gd��=�T�/-���ᱮ<��}5�d��</���� =��C��ýP��������Kx�$c��lt8��J��T���2��g)�↵U�2I���y��`�����ּ�l�6��S���2'h�!�GK�o��i�&� �������[Oŝ�F���Nu� ���e?3�↵���裱�������6�8\�G�qԒr���`�����z�Gc����������>1��t�rʤ����=�V�D�D]#���=_f�釘~`v+����A��;c�{�x����m-���L�T�>�L��H�J���OL�w�{�@,�v������Ъ{�Ɍ�:�Y���@��Κ�O�h廤�D��e�]00| D�������y|ՙ5�����#������G�ϊ�)LR��1Jb��)�S����7j��t�-�'���R"���(��B������3N�(��S�($����>8pW���~͟�x۵6T{�)5��U�j�́��↵k�lˑ�)-� Ha�7�( ��C��Y���{+g��ũ[[ʣ>_0y��aNiO����ݡ��ϯ�lm��~����o����#&jC�^�*����:s����k:�h�޽Ѝ��ޖ9��L����a��5����e�2�a�&���8��ZT���;O���$  n��!�a�l�8�3�k2�<���������I#��*0���C؃��O����(��b)��Iע.����vլ�u���b*��#����m�e�XJflɇ�@T"���f��s��7�=�9�'���툗↵H�F~g�5g=�kh[~5M2�4u�� ����(>��W�W��\4�)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1J�П�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��+�D�Y5�Y2*��2j��Jt�L���5�`���(������r    �#�� ��ڱ��_I/N^P�����f�Z������xuuu��XNav��[��Kȹ)���v�����D�2&�������HծŸ��+y����a"��H�k�{3lj��yg�_���2�v,c���������X��_�;��4USQo>Ij'�(���)7Oڐ(���%ad�GO��{�<�EA����̽����V�.�e�]���H\�}�vL�����8%�n��n���t�' ���!o��~������O9;��ꚇ��>��/t��lZ%�\J�!D}��������.ruي�����d�3��۔(�t����L2G0Ϯ������"��7*��>�9$�Nr�/�!&?嚲Kg��a�*�bun��"���z���42�(w�{�u,�'�����������↵.@�o-��Kg?���������\   �B��� ?AyP��;~����D�VJ��$����'�jW��z}�u��Z���AS��b����8Ip�Mf���Ep���!TF���_�h�3�U�ʹ���M���������������ڢ↵��_ �q�m������_�k�W/7�<~/������O����?ɗ��?mv�_D�V���M�   6+�S��=o�P)�������G����>3�7��K%���?69���F�����}�Fo��?����"��W����Y�D$�����{���*d↵o��oHJ�e��){���2޻�-�{`L7Ww�zGm ���,Ujӂ;�q��D
�c  ��&c��&�O\~�>ZM,�]��]��ح�g���[�͗hC��&��_�b����#�{��|����m��0�t�����k�?�)��ʹ�8�|����E���f�~�1D�T����sV~�^�@%����ͮ���%YZ��a{��Qi�^�N�ju�J���cw���V�c�.�.���֑�\K;��x�����a���lUG��P�[�VQ9���~�e����^�<iV>G^�7Z�Z#��w}���߷�~�~���%Ք#����,�lRu�J_��n�2�3r�MGV�Kf����鏆!�X�(�>���;cmM-Um��<��9Ǚ�����C��\zb�jݻv��j��Z�j�M�6n��nݺ$*h��)�SI��(��(�JP���L��]�,NI=I'�&�����l⹦)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)_�џ�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��ҟ�)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb��)�S��)LR��1Jb���"
headers
:
{last-modified: "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 16:02:07 GMT", content-type: "image/jpeg", cache-control: "public, max-age=0", content-disposition: "attachment; filename="sample_logo.jpg""}
```

This is the response from the server. The server is sending a file. How do I recreate the same file using the `content-type` in header and `data`, and force-download it?

Comment: Many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file) out there. And this is related to binary file response https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob. Using filereader API https://gist.github.com/robnyman/1875344

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the response has already been parsed to `json`. Once it is parsed to `json`, `binary data` is parsed to `string`, and lost some information.

Even converting back to `blob` cannot retrieve the missing data. Hence, the generated file is corrupted.

Try to get the result as a `stream`, and directly convert to `blob`. That will do the trick.